# For Loop with Filtering and following Regression in R

Tags: r, filter, linear-regression

I tried to code a "for loop" which filters values in a column and then performs a linear model for every iteration.

What did I do wrong?

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)

for (temp_var in x){
 filter(vek,store_id == x)
  {lmtest <- lm(UNITS ~ store_id,
                           data = vek  )   }}
```

Comment: Can you share your output and what you expected to get?

Comment: Also, x <- c(1,2,3,4) is harder than x <- 1:4.

Comment: First, the output of your `filter()` command is not being assigned to a variable so it is not being used in the linear model. Second, the `lmtest` variable is being overwritten with each iteration of the loop. Third, you should be filtering by `store_id == temp_var` in each iteration of the loop, because it is the variable being incremented with each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

special thanks to @qdread, with your comments I was able to fix this:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
sink("D:\\test.txt")
for (temp_var in x){
y <- filter(vek,store_id == temp_var)
lmtest <- lm(UNITS ~ store_id,
             data = y             )  

print(summary(lmtest))

  }
sink()
```